# Pull image from local docker registry with IP

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I have created a locale docker registry in my system and pushed one image into it. When I tried to pull image as **"docker pull localhost:5000/image_name"**, it pulls the images from registry. But if I try to pull image as **"docker pull 192.168.2.54:5000/image_name"** , it gives an error as **"Error response from daemon: Get https://192.168.2.54:5000/v1/_ping: EOF "**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you're not running a secure registry. See the notes here about how to use an insecure registry:

https://docs.docker.com/registry/insecure/

Comment: I configured unsecured registry using self singed certificate. Now I am getting different error message as " Get myregistrydomain.com:5000/v1/_ping: dial tcp: lookup myregistrydomain.com on 192.168.2.5:53: no such host".